# Test Firebase AdWords conversion tracking

Tags: ios, firebase, google-ads-api, firebase-analytics

In our iOS project we are using Firebase Analytics. We are also running AdWords campaign to get downloads.

I have enabled conversion tracking following https://firebase.google.com/docs/adwords/ for first_opens.

How do I test if this working or not?

Comment: Hi Mitul, you found any solutions?

Comment: @KirthikaVijayakumar nope